Telegram WebApp Authentication
We have a website that also works as a Telegram webapp for our bot. We're having an issue exchanging the unique user token to bearer token, provided to him/her when the bot runs /start command. Our website uses bearer token for user authentication, and stores it in a cookie for authorization.
The problem is, when I create a link to webapp with a query parameter startapp, the webapp doesn't receive that parameter, and therefore cannot exchange it for bearer token.
What is the proper way to pass a query parameter to webapp via a link like t.me/MyBot/MyApp?startapp=uniquetoken that's accessible inside of it?
I tried passing it via start_param, startapp and startattach, all to no avail. According to the docs I'm supposed to pass it via startapp, but it doesn't seem to work.

Since you're using direct links to open your app, you might not be looking in the right place. There are two spots you can check.

You can use direct links to open a Mini App directly in the current
chat. If a non-empty startapp parameter is included in the link, it
will be passed to the Mini App in the start_param field and in the GET
parameter tgWebAppStartParam.

With tgWebAppStartParam:
const queryParamters = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryParamters);
const uniquetoken = urlParams.get('tgWebAppStartParam');

With start_param:
let uniquetoken = window.Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe.start_param

Reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#direct-link-mini-apps

Thank you for the answer, I found the issue - the Telegram Web App file wasn't initialized properly, and the data weren't being sent to back-end.
